# How do I keep a mod private and use it in another module within the same project in Rust?

Tags: rust, module, visibility

So I want to have some modules defined in `lib.rs` but not make them public but only available for use within the project.

in my `lib.rs`, if I have the definition as this:

```
pub mod args;
```

in my `main.rs`, I can use the `args` modules this way:

```
use my_lib::args::Cli;
```

where `my_lib` is defined in `Cargo.tml` as

```
[lib]
name = "my_lib"
path = "src/lib.rs"
```

but I don't want `pub mod args;`. I tried changing to `pub(crate) mod args;` but this leads to compilation error that the `args` module cannot be found.

How do I make a module like `args` defined in `lib.rs` available without have to give it the most permissive visibility?

Comment: While they're in the same project, the "lib" and "main" bits of a project *are different crates*, in fact you can have any number of "bin" entry points, all of which are different crates, and different from lib. Thus anything of lib you want to use in bin has to be externally accessible. Some possibilities are to not have a `lib` at all, or to also declare `lib` as a module of main, though that leads to internal complexities if you split it out as it's now part of multiple crates with different names & paths.

Comment: @Masklinn do you know if it is possible to write integration tests against code in bin (ie code not in lib?) The reason why I ended up splitting into lib was I found out I could not write integration tests unless I do this. Maybe I am wrong? If not then I am pretty much stuck with having to split things

Comment: An integration test against a binary would be invocations of the binary itself so not really. If you split content out of the binary in order to make it more testable, I would suggest moving *everything* to the `lib`, exposing just the one entry point (a function, possibly a function taking args), and having `main.rs` just be `fn main() { my_lib::main() }`

Comment: Yeah. What I have is exactly what you described and it works fine. I was just wondering about the `pub mod args;` in the lib.rs. But from my understanding I can't avoid this and things in lib.rs will have to be public

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Rust separates the library `lib.rs` and binary `main.rs` into separate crates there is no simple way to include things that are in `lib.rs` and not `pub` from `main.rs`.

I suggest you follow the way of big crates ([`serde` comes to mind](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/src/serde/lib.rs.html#305)) and add a `pub mod __private;` which conveys the meaning. You can additionaly annotate it with `#[doc(hidden)]` to hide it from the documentation making it even more obvious.